# Cannot SSH after switching to Netgear router

Tags: bash, shell, networking, ssh

I have Comcast Xfinity internet. When I was sent their Wifi router/Cable modem combo box, I was able to use SSH perfectly. However, since the Wifi from the box was weak, I decided to buy my own router: a Netgear WNR2500. I then called Comcast to put their router into "Bridge mode" so I can use the wifi from the netgear router.

However, after that switch I can no longer SSH into my Amazon AWS instance.

Here's the last lines of the log after running: ssh -vvv -i mypermissions.pem ec2-user@ec2-***********.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

```
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

This is on a Macbook Air, which worked before the router switch. However, using a Windows computer with PuTTY, everything works great, even now after the router switch.

I'm really stuck and have been fighting with this problem for several days, so any help is tremendously appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any error message? If so, which?

Comment: your logs don't indicate an error, perhaps you're getting an error earlier? There could be also an issue with your ssh configuration. Try to `mv ~/.ssh ~/.ssh-bak`. This will require you to accept the new fingerprint of the server. Lastly, you could compare the logs from `PuTTY` and `ssh`.

Comment: @Sebastian, that didn't fix it.

I was able to fix the issue by adding -o "ProxyCommand nc %h %p" to the ssh command  - though I don't know why it works. And there don't seem to be any errors earlier in the log.